# How to find a commuting element in group of permutaions

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Find an element of $S_{10}\setminus A_{10}$ commuting with the element
$ \tau = (1 2 3 4 5)(6 7 8 9 10)$
of $A_{10}$.
The solution to the problem just gives the answer

> Set $\pi = (16)(27)(38)(49)(5 10). \pi$ is a good choice because $\pi\tau\pi^{-1}=\tau$

I could find $\pi$ as a product of two 5-cycles but then $\pi \in A_{10} $ so it wouldn't be valid.
I know that given $\pi\tau\pi^{-1}=\tau$
$(\pi(\tau_1)\pi(\tau_2)\pi(\tau_3)\cdots\pi(\tau_n))=\tau$ will find $\pi$ if $\pi$ has the same cycle structure as $\tau$
How is it solved if $\pi$ doesn't have the same cycle structure as $\tau$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two elements $\tau$ and $\pi$ commute iff $\pi \tau \pi^{-1} = \tau$. That is, $\pi$ conjugates $\tau$ to $\tau$. Given two elements of $S_n$ in the same conjugacy class, it is easy to construct the element that induces the conjugation: align the two elements by cycle structure and draw an arrow from top to bottom. In this case, write
\begin{align*}
\tau &= (1,2,3,4,\,5)\;(6,7,8,9,10) \\
&= (6,7,8,9,10)(1,2,3,4,5)
\end{align*}
Thus an example of a conjugating element maps 1 to 6, 2 to 7, 3 to 8, etc. That is,
$$\pi = (1,6)(2,7)(3,8)(4,9)(5,10).$$
Note that this method allows us to find every element in the centralizer of $\tau$, showing an intimate connection between centralizers and conjugacy classes (in fact, by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, $|C_G(\tau)|\cdot|\text{conj.class of } \tau| = |G|$).

Comment: Thanks makes sense. If i were to write   \begin{align*}
\tau &= (1,2,3,4,\,5)\;(6,7,8,9,10) \\
&= (7,8,9,10,6)(1,2,3,4,5)
\end{align*} and do the same process would that also be valid since (6,7,8,9,10)=(7,8,9,10,6)?

Comment: @MitchHughes yes absolutely, and in this case $\pi = (1,7,2,8,3,9,4,10,5,6)$ which is also not in $A_{10}$.